# Collections sort not working properly

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am new to Java. I am trying to added few words from a text file to my existing text based word list. I have the below code doing

1. Add words from an file to existing list
2. Sort the list of words
3. Save the words to a text file

"wordList" is an arraylist with existing words.

```
    private void updateDictionaryFile(String filepath) {
    String textCurrentLine = "";

    BufferedReader dictionaryFile = null;
    try {

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("fileScanner.hasNextLine()  "+  fileScanner.hasNextLine());
            textCurrentLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            if(textCurrentLine.length() > 0)
            if (!wordList.contains(textCurrentLine)) {
                wordList.add(textCurrentLine);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(wordList);

        String newFile = filepath.replace(".txt", "_new.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
        for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
            pw.println(wordList.get(i).toString());
        }
        pw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (dictionaryFile != null) {
                dictionaryFile.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Word listed in new file is not sorted. Am I missing something in between?

Below is the output

```
A
Achieve
Although
Anything
Ask
Avoid
Badly
Bluma
But
Find
Forget
Goal
Goals
How
In
It
Just
Keep
Know
NOT
Often
Once
One
Psychologists
Reasoning
Reject
Remember
Research
Russian
Shifting
Sidestep
So
Sometimes
Start
Stop
The
This
Those
Under
Visualise
Visualising
We
What
When
With
You
Zeigarnik
a
aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
aardvark
aardwolf
aargh
aarrgh
aarrghh
aas
```

Comment: Does it change the order of the strings in the output file?

Comment: I assure you that `Collections.sort()` is working properly.

Comment: An example of the content of input and output files would be helpful.

Comment: Well I am new  to Java. I can add the output, its pretty long list. I don't understand why down votes. It would great for people who down voted to point out the mistake and comment. Reason I have come and asked you people is because I am unable to find out the reason why its going wrong.

Comment: @JamesShaji downvotes on a question are used to ***encourage*** a user to improve the question mainly. They indicate that visitors feel that the question doesn't contain enough useful information to answer the question.  In this case, after 27 minutes you still haven't shown the exact definition of `wordList` which people think could be relevant to your problem.  And only after 27 minutes you added the output, which shows that ByteCode's answer, posted 13 minutes after your question, was right all along...

Comment: @fvu Well I can agree output could have made the question better. However 3 downvotes is pretty too much for that. Where else can some one point out mistakes in the question?

Comment: @JamesShaji that's what the comments are for, and the different weak spots of the question were all pointed out pretty quickly in this case.  I'm sure your next question will be better :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collections.sort(wordList);` will work perfectly. if need to ignore the case then use below code.

```
Collections.sort(wordList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: Thanks ByteCode for the solution. Java looks a little strange for me when compared to flex and actionscript.